# Firebase Cloud functions - Is there a good way to get the first two documents created in a collection?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a React-Native app that utilizes cloud functions to monitor users who join a room. When a user clicks on the join room button, they are added to a collection as a document and wait for another user to join. Is there a good way to monitor the first collection for 2+ documents and then take the users in pairs and assign them to a second collection? (IE, user A joins and waits in the queue collection. User B then joins and a function moves the documents for both user A and B into the new collection as 1 document).

Here is what I have so far for monitoring when a user joins the waiting room:

```
 exports.getUsersFromQueued = functions.firestore
  .document('Queued Games/{user}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    // perform desired operations
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

While Firestore does track when a document was created, it has no way to query on this internal metadata. So if you want to be able to query on the documents that were first created, you'll have to add a field with the `creationDate` to the data in each document and then order/filter on that.